# Bug with Android 4.3 ImageView method getImageMatrix()

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I recently upgraded to Android 4.4 and someone of the features of my app have surprisingly stopped working.

I have this code for initializing and then drawing my custom view. The basic idea is it adjusts the zoom level so the entire view fits on the screen.

```
private void initAtZoomLevel(float zoomLevel){
    ....
    Matrix transformMatrix = new Matrix();
    transformMatrix.setScale(initialZoomLevel, initialZoomLevel);
    float yTransCenter = (screenHeight - mapHeight)/2.0f;
    setImageMatrix(transformMatrix);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float[] values = new float[9];
    getImageMatrix().getValues(values);
    scaleFactor = values[0];
    ....
}
```

*THIS WORKS ON ANDROID 4.1.2, and 4.2.2 DEVICES I HAVE*

**But on Android 4.4/4.3 `getImageMatrix().getValues(values)` stopped working!**
It returns an identity matrix instead of the transform matrix I expect on app start up!

**DEBUG PRINT-OUT:**

*4.1.2*: @`setImageMatrix(transformMatrix)`:  `transformMatrix = Matrix{[0.025122833, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.025122833, 566.5][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

@`getImageMatrix().getValues(values)`: `transformMatrix = Matrix{[0.025122833, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.025122833, 566.5][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

*4.4*: @`setImageMatrix(transformMatrix)`:  `transformMatrix = Matrix{[0.025122833, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.025122833, 553.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

@`getImageMatrix().getValues(values)`: `transformMatrix = Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

I've looked around and I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Somehow the image matrix for my view is being reset; has Android 4.4 changed the way we are supposed to do this? Has anyone else run in to this problem?

*note: the problem appears to have originated on Android 4.3 - the same problem occurs running on an emulator*

**UPDATE:** I have checked the [change log from 4.2 to 4.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes.html), but there is nothing on there I can see above the Matrix Class, or anything relevant to the View class.

**UPDATE 2:** My pinch-to-zoom is also not working, which uses the same `setImageMatrix()` method - and it's clearly not sticking because nothing happens in `getImageMatrix().getValues()`

Comment: Try diffing the actual source code of getImageMatrix between Android versions

Comment: @GenericHolidayName if you look closely, it's actually not saving/returning the same matrix (the field names are different between `getImageMatrix` and `setImageMatrix`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446099/how-to-extend-imageview-correctly-in-android-the-following-code-is-not-renderin

Anyone who know the issue for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my previous answer does outline the overall problem, it in fact might not be a bug. As pointed out by Generic Holiday Name, `mDrawMatrix` *should be* set to `mMatrix` in the `configureBounds()` method - which would eliminate this problem/bug/whatever.

*HOWEVER*, I had to add several lines of code to get `configureBounds()` to actually work:

```
private void configureBounds() {
    if (mDrawable == null || !mHaveFrame) {
        return;
    }

    int dwidth = mDrawableWidth;
    int dheight = mDrawableHeight;

    ...

    if (dwidth <= 0 || dheight <= 0 || ScaleType.FIT_XY == mScaleType) {
        /* If the drawable has no intrinsic size, or we're told to
            scaletofit, then we just fill our entire view.
        */
        mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, vwidth, vheight);
        mDrawMatrix = null;
    } else {
             //here's the where mDrawMatrix == mMatrix IF using scaleType.MATRIX
             ...
    }
}
```

---

**So, in order to actually get this to work the way I expect with 4.2 and below you need to make sure:**

1. `mDrawable != null`. This wasn't a problem before, but for my case I wasn't using a drawable so everything was failing (the `return` statement was hit right away)
2. `'dwidth >0 && dheight >0`. This isn't a problem if you have a real drawable, but like I said, I didn't.
3. `mHaveFrame = true`. I had no idea what this was - never used it. The only way to set this to true is by calling `setFrame(int, int, int, int)`.

**To get my scaling code to work again, I had to add the following:**

```
 //potentially a fix for the "bug" that appears in Android 4.3+
 //mDrawable cannot be null anymore for getImageMatrix to work---stupid
 //therefore the imageview class MUST set a drawable for matrix scaling to work
 //so here I am using a "empty" drawable to get around this
 ShapeDrawable fakeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(); //so mDrawable != null
 fakeDrawable.setIntrinsicHeight(1); //so dwidth and dheight are > 0
 fakeDrawable.setIntrinsicWidth(1);

 setImageDrawable(fakeDrawable);

 setFrame(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight); //setting a frame so mHaveFrame = true
```

*YIKES*

Comment: btw, the added code was placed in the constructor/initialization methods for my custom imageview

Answer (score 2):

I have found what I believe to be the problem. I took a look at the source code for `ImageView` and discovered the `setImageMatrix(Matrix matrix)` is saving the matrix in a different field than `getImageMatrix()` is returning...

**Android 4.4 ImageView**

```
public void setImageMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    // collaps null and identity to just null
    if (matrix != null && matrix.isIdentity()) {
        matrix = null;
    }

    // don't invalidate unless we're actually changing our matrix
    if (matrix == null && !mMatrix.isIdentity() ||
            matrix != null && !mMatrix.equals(matrix)) {
        mMatrix.set(matrix);
        configureBounds();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Here the matrix is being stored in the field **mMatrix**

```
public Matrix getImageMatrix() {
    if (mDrawMatrix == null) { //<-- should be mMatrix == null
        return new Matrix(Matrix.IDENTITY_MATRIX);
    }
    return mDrawMatrix; //<-- NOT THE RIGHT FIELD TO RETURN
}
```

While `getImageMatrix()` returns **mDrawMatrix...**

**Android 4.1.2 ImageView**

```
public Matrix getImageMatrix() {
    return mMatrix;
}

public void setImageMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
    // collaps null and identity to just null
    if (matrix != null && matrix.isIdentity()) {
        matrix = null;
    }

    // don't invalidate unless we're actually changing our matrix
    if (matrix == null && !mMatrix.isIdentity() ||
            matrix != null && !mMatrix.equals(matrix)) {
        mMatrix.set(matrix);
        configureBounds();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

*both methods use the same field* - **mMatrix**

So there's the problem right there --- all of a sudden `getImageMatrix()` is returning the wrong field...

Comment: To try to resolve, make sure your `scaleType` is set to `ScaleType.MATRIX`. It looks like `mMatrix` should get assigned to `mDrawMatrix` in `configureBounds()` **if** the `scaleType` is set correctly. It looks like this is actually a *fix* to enforce the `scaleType` more than a new bug.

Comment: I could have sworn I had that somewhere... time to go see if that's the problem

Comment: You may be right. That's just what it looks like to me. Previously, it wouldn't matter if `mDrawMatrix` was assigned or not, because it wasn't returned.

Comment: there is a line `if(ScaleType.MATRIX == mScaleType) {... mDrawMatrix = mMatrix}`, BUT - the first line of `configureBounds()` is `if (mDrawable == null || !mHaveFrame) {
            return;
        }`. So it's going to immediately return and bypass setting `mDrawMatrix = mMatrix`.

Comment: Is your drawable `null`? That could definitely explain it.

Comment: yeah, i never set a drawable - i need use the `ImageView` to draw hundreds of small rectangles, text, etc that change with zoom level so I was under the impression when I first started the project that I couldn't use a `Drawable`... it worked up until now, but maybe I made an incorrect assumption?

Comment: You could try using a dummy drawable to force `configureBounds` to run. I can understand why they don't bother setting bounds on a null drawable, so I think that may be a good workaround.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was an "incorrect assumption", though. Not knowing that it has to now run through `configureBounds` to return the "correct" matrix seems pretty reasonable, since it didn't have to before.

Comment: setting a dummy drawable alone didn't work, but I did get it to work - making a separate answer.